# how to solved django OperationalError - attempt to write a readonly database?

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu, apache2

I have Django web in linux(digitalocean), and use sqlite3. I have three users sqlite3.

When I use: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --> everything is good.

But When I use: sudo systemctl restart apache2 --> when I open user login page and when logging, I receive error: attempt to write a readonly database.

I tried:

1. sudo chmod a+w db.sqlite3
2. chown apache:apache db.sqlite3

Folder structure:

```
-myproject
--projectenv
--myapp
----myapp
----firstapp
----manage.py
----db.sqlite3
```

DATABASES :

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
}
```

}

Comment: Please show us the actual full permissions on the db file.

Comment: @JohnGordon how can I show full permissions?

Comment: Run this command `ls -la db.sqlite3` and post the output.

Comment: @JohnGordon   -rw-rw-r-- 1 root www-data 307200  <-- this is output, How can I change it?

Comment: if I used chmod 777 myapp and chmod 664 db.sqlite3 --> everything is good. but, is this recommendation: used chmod 777 myapp?

Answer (score 1):

While processing, Sqlite writes a bunch of temporary files, so Apache needs write permission to the ***directory*** that sqlite is writing those files into - which can be the directory that contains the database file (`myapp` in your case).
https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html

If your situation allows, ***for testing purposes only***, try giving everyone full access to the directory containing your database: `chmod 777 myapp`.
If this fixes your issue, then you can move the database file into a separate directory and grant apache ownership of that directory for a more sensible solution.

Comment: if I used chmod 777 myapp and  chmod 664 db.sqlite3 --> everything is good.  but, is this recommendation: used chmod 777 myapp?

Comment: No, absolutely not. You just need to give apache (which usually goes by the username `www-data`) write permission to the directory that sqlite wants to write the temporary files to ([see here for directories](https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#temporary_file_storage_locations)). There are different ways to go about this. For instance, you could give ownership of the directory to apache (`chown www-data:www-data`), or you could grant write permission for a group and then assign apache to that group, or assign yourself to apache's group and assign apache's group to the directory.

Comment: To make it clear: ´chmod 777` is never a good idea. Here are some more tips to solve your issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/57596/why-do-i-get-sqlite-error-unable-to-open-database-file

Comment: thanks. I will read the mentioned issues in detail.

Comment: I solved the error and please answer, is this the right way? or is it dangerous? --> in db.sqlite3 directory "sudo chown www-data .  and chmod 755 myapp.       this is that similar : https://serverfault.com/questions/57596/why-do-i-get-sqlite-error-unable-to-open-database-file

Comment: Kind of yes, but that will make apache the owner of the `myapp` directory, which is probably not what you want going forward since it is your project directory. I suggest moving the database file into a separate subdirectory and then giving apache write permission to that subdirectory. Don't forget to update your Django database settings to point at the new path: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#name

Comment: This seems to be a sensible solution: https://serverfault.com/a/499207 They 1.) moved the file into a subfolder, 2.) gave apache ownership of that subfolder, 3.) added themselves to the apache group, and then 4.) gave write access to that group.